# Present single image on any screen correctly

Tags: html, css, image

We are developing a webapp using Angular.JS and we need to present single image on a screen of either a smartphone, tablet or pc. We need the image to expoilt the maximum size of the screen without stretching the image. For example if the image width is much larger than the image height than on smartphone the image will use 100% of the width of the screen and in proportion to that will be the hight of the image. Currently, we use HTML, CSS and Bootstrap.

Comment: so, what did you try?

Comment: so, do you want to maintain aspect ratio of the img?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to measure the windows width and height.

Here's something I do always.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="mybg">&nbsp;</div>
```

**Style:**

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
.mybg{background: url(http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg) no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(window).load(function(){
        var w,h;
        w = $(window).width();
        h = $(window).height();
        $('.mybg').width(w); 
        $('.mybg').height(h);           
    });
```